# Python Scrapy - yield not working but print() does

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl websites and count the occurrence of keywords on each page.

[Modifying code from this article](https://www.phooky.com/blog/find-specific-words-on-web-pages-with-scrapy/)

Using print() will at least output results when running the crawler like so:

`scrapy crawl webcrawler > output.csv`

However, the output.csv is not formatted well. I should be using yield (or return) however in that case the CSV/JSON outputted is blank.

Here is my spider code

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

import re

from ..items import keyword

df = pd.read_csv(r'python\scrapy-1\web_scraping_websites.csv', index_col=0)

class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "webcrawler"

    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
    }

    allowed_domains = df.domain.head(5).to_list()
    start_urls = df.url.head(5).to_list()
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=False, callback="parse")]

    def parse(self, response):

        terms = ['canidae', 'felidae', 'cat', 'cattle', 'dog', 'donkey', 'goat', 'guinea pig', 'horse', 'pig', 'rabbit']

        response_body = response.body.decode('utf-8')

        url = response.url
        domain = url.split('/')[2]

        results = []
        
        for x in terms:

            t = re.findall(x, response_body, re.IGNORECASE)

            result2 = keyword()
            result2["url"] = url
            result2["domain"] = domain
            result2["term"] = x
            result2["matches"] = len(t)

            results.append(result2)

        print(results) #print sort of works
        # yield results #Does not work...

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if getattr(response, "encoding", None) != None:
                return CrawlSpider._requests_to_follow(self, response)
        else:
                return []
```

Comment: Using this print statement as a workaround 
```print('"' + url + '","' + domain + '","' + x + '","' + str(len(t)) + '"')```

Comment: `yield` doesn't print anything.  Never has.  You just need to change your print statement to print in the format you want.

Comment: @TimRoberts Based on your comment I think you're not familiar with Scrapy framework. Yield is used to output scrape results to json/csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by rewriting the `parse` method more carefully.
The blog post provided the basic idea: loop over the response body for each keyword you need. But instead of using a for loop, using a list comprehension to build the list of matches worked well with `yield`

```
    def parse(self, response):
        #yield the response url
        #and the keyword matches...

        response_body = response.body.decode('utf-8')

        url = response.url
        domain = url.split('/')[2]

        item = SfscrapeItem()
        item['url'] = url
        item['domain'] = domain
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['matches'] = [str(len(re.findall(keyword, response_body, re.IGNORECASE))) for keyword in keywords]
        
        yield item
```